# Access to $ share

Tags: windows

On most servers I can access `\\server\e$` but on one particular server I can't access it on my own machine.

On other machines it works fine.

I previously had a share set up to a file within this `e$` and I had problems and I had to disconnect this drive. I wonder has this not been cleanly removed.

Also other users, that have this share `\\server\e$\folder1\folder2` mapped don't seem to be able to open `\\server\e$`

Any idea what might be happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibilities:

- DNS name resolution to `server`
- Network connectivity to TCP port 445 on `server`
- You are not an administrator of `server`
- `server` does not have an E: drive or it is disconnected
- The LanManServer (Server) service is not running on `server`
- The LanManWorkstation (Workstation) service on your client may have erroneous data in its cache. Try restarting the service.

I could tell you more with a packet capture.

Comment: Thanks very much. All it needed was a restart of the Workstation service on my client. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear my shotgun approach was on target. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by hitting that little green checkmark.